# how to pass the data parsed with xmlpullparser to another class?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, rss, xmlpullparser

im trying to parse a xml with xmlpullparser, im already getting title,author,guid on the rows of the ListView.

im following this tutorial :

http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2013/04/xml-pull-parser-example-in-android.html

how to pass that data parsed(from the list view) to a singlemessage class(the new class that opens when i tap each row of the list view)?

Comment: In android, you don't open a class. You can show a dialog, start an activity or switch to another fragment. Which one would you like to do and in which context?

Comment: sorry,maybe my question was wrong.what im trying is : when i tap a single row of the list view(which already has data parsed),it opens a new screen with the title,author,description tags and three buttons(button1=get the audio from some link,button2=get the video from some link,button3 get the website from a link).

Comment: is the new screen an activity?

Comment: yeah, its going to be.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass data to an activity, you can use putExtra method, before starting the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity,NewScreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("title", string); 
startActivity(intent);
```

To access the variable in new NewScreenActivity, in onCreate method, do this:

```
String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
```